# RabbitMQ + Memory Limits

Tags: memory, memory-management, rabbitmq

I'm just looking in to the config details of RabbitMQ and came across

```
[{rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0}, 
           {disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 1.0}}
          ]
}]
```

What does this config mean?

`vm_memory_high_watermark` set to 0 means => Block all publishers immediately the rabbitmq app starts? But we still see rabbitmq able to queue whatever msgs we send.

```
16720 rabbitmq  20   0  142m  62m 2408 S    0  **1.6**   0:06.88 beam.smp
```

Whenever we send msgs to the broker we se this process' memory usage increasing. So, Does this mean the msgs are in memory although the watermark is set to 0?

We are curious to know what happens if the mem limit of ram reaches and still msgs are being sent? Either publishers are blocked? or The messages are swapped out to disk if available?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The vm_memory_high_watermark is a percentage value is related to memory flow control in RabbitMQ.

If you take a look at [Memory flow control](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html) you will see that it says, under "Memory-Based Flow Control" heading:

> The RabbitMQ server detects the total amount of RAM installed in the computer on startup and when rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark fraction is executed. By default, when the RabbitMQ server uses above 40% of the installed RAM, it raises a memory alarm and blocks all connections. Once the memory alarm has cleared (e.g. due to the server paging messages to disk or delivering them to clients) normal service resumes.

So by you setting this value to 0, then of course it will trigger straight away! If you want RabbitMQ to be allowed to use more memory then you will want to INCREASE the value.

Another important note:

> The default memory threshold is set to 40% of installed RAM. Note that this does not prevent the RabbitMQ server from using more than 40%, it is merely the point at which publishers are throttled.

So if you try yo publish messages when the alarm has been raised then your publishers will be blocked from sending messages.

If you want to block all publishers then you would set the vm_memory_high_watermark to 0. If you want to 'disable' memory based flow control then set the vm_memory_high_watermark to 100. See details from above link:

> A value of 0 makes the memory alarm go off immediately and thus disables all publishing (this may be useful if you wish to disable publishing globally; use rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0). To prevent the memory alarm from going off at all, set some high multiplier such as 100.

Comment: Ya I had gone through that doc. What do you mean by throttled [% of msgs might be dropped] and blocked [no msgs can be sent]? If I specify 0% then alarm should be turned on the moment app starts rite? then all publisher messages should be blocked rite? or throttled? what happens if I had completely disabled memory-based flow control [0%]?

Comment: Throttled in this situation will result in the publishers being blocked completely (because the alarm has been triggered). If you specify 0% then you're right, the alarm will be triggered and all the publishers will be blocked. If you want to disable memory based flow control set the value to 100, 0 will just block everything

Comment: Actually we just ran the basic sender example and found that msgs being sent but now we noticed that msgs are not being received. So, as a whole we should have some ram mem for messages so that rmq can atleast swap out msgs in need to disk

Comment: "set the vm_memory_high_watermark to 100" Shouldn't that be 1 as it is fractional number?

Comment: @dmourati is correct, it should be set to `1` to be the equivalent of `100%`. so if you wish to keep it but at a lower amount, let's say `90%` the value should be `0.9`